# how to get a transformed xml file with all child tags of every occurance of parent tag under only one parent tag

Tags: xslt

I am using this input xml file .

```
                 <Content>
                <body><text>xxx</text></body>
                    <body><text>yy</text></body>
               <body><text>zz</text></body>
               <body><text>kk</text></body>
                   <body><text>mmm</text></body>
                        </Content>
```

after Xslt transformation the output should be

```
                        <Content>
                 <body><text>xxx</text>
                       <text>yy</text>
                           <text>zz</text>
                     <text>kk</text>
                   <text>mmm</text></body>
                     </Content>
```

Can anyone please provide its relavant Xsl file.

Comment: The Xsl code should be such that for all traversal of parent tag 'body',I need to get only one 'body' tag to be created. Part of xsl is as shown that i have tried. <xsl:for-each select="body"> <text><xsl:value-of select="text" /></text></xsl:for-each> but here only text tags are created.And I don't want <body> tag to be hardcoded like <text> tag above. It should be created such that for entire body tags traversal only one <body> tag need to be created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="body"/>
 <xsl:template match="body[1]">
  <body>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="../body/node()"/>
  </body>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Content>
    <body>
        <text>xxx</text>
    </body>
    <body>
        <text>yy</text>
    </body>
    <body>
        <text>zz</text>
    </body>
    <body>
        <text>kk</text>
    </body>
    <body>
        <text>mmm</text>
    </body>
</Content>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Content>
   <body>
      <text>xxx</text>
      <text>yy</text>
      <text>zz</text>
      <text>kk</text>
      <text>mmm</text>
   </body>
</Content>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** copies every node "as-is".
2. It is overriden by two templates. The first ignores/deletes every `body` element`.
3. The second template overriding the identity template also overrides the first such template (that deletes every `body` element) for any `body` element that is the first `body` child of its parent. For this first `body` child only, a `body` element is generated and in its body all nodes that are children nodes of any `body` child of its parent (the current `body` elements and all of its `body` siblings) are processed.

Comment: according to my understanding(correct me if iam wrong).The third template will match the first body tag and then inside the template instead of processing its own text tag it will go to the parent tag of body i.e,Content ( as '../' represents the same)process all the text tags of all body tags(as '../body/node()' ) and copy the same.

Comment: My question is 'when we are processing only first body child of its parent why there is a necessity of second template which deletes every body child'.I tried removing the second template and included only identity and 3rd template but not getting the desired output.Can you explain the reason behind this.

Comment: Understood that apply-templates will apply templates on all its siblings if anyone of it is given in its 'match' attribute.Thanks.

Comment: @Jeevan: You are welcome. I see that you came to the correct answers to your questions.

Comment: Oh!! Is it. This xslt is something intresting to learn and apply.

Comment: @Jeevan: Yes, XSLT is both powerful and elegant.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <xsl:template match="Content">
      <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="body/text"/>
      </body>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="body/text">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```