# Get child node to show for every parent node

Tags: xslt

I know this may sound like a common problem, but I have tried all the similar solutions on this site with no success. Right now I am trying to use an xslt to transform an existing xml document into an xml document that conforms to a new schema. I am trying to get name and partnum to show up for every product. But instead I just get one product node with all the names and partnums in it. I have tried using a for each loop, i have tried this solution [how to get a transformed xml file with all child tags of every occurance of parent tag under only one parent tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598386/how-to-get-a-transformed-xml-file-with-all-child-tags-of-every-occurance-of-pare) with very close results but the only problem is I get all product terminating tags nested within a product tag.

Here is my current xml:

```
<CATALOG>

<PRODUCT NAME="18 Volt Cordless DRILL" PARTNUM="12">
    <SPECIFICATIONS><WEIGHT>8 oz. </WEIGHT><POWER>18 Volt</POWER></SPECIFICATIONS>
    <OPTIONS FINISH="Polished"/>
    <PRICE>     <MSRP>139.99</MSRP>
    <WHOLESALE>89.99</WHOLESALE><SHIPPING>10.00</SHIPPING></PRICE>
    <NOTES>On sale for $99.99 for one week only.</NOTES>
</PRODUCT>
<PRODUCT NAME="Variable Speed Drill Press" PARTNUM="76" CATEGORY="Shop-Professional">
    <SPECIFICATIONS><WEIGHT>100 lbs.</WEIGHT><POWER>120 Volt</POWER></SPECIFICATIONS>
    <OPTIONS FINISH="Metal"/>
    <PRICE> <MSRP>299.99</MSRP>
<WHOLESALE>199.99</WHOLESALE><SHIPPING>50.00</SHIPPING></PRICE>
    <NOTES>Ground shipping only.</NOTES>
</PRODUCT>
<PRODUCT NAME="Gas powered generator" PARTNUM="54" CATEGORY="Shop-Professional">
    <SPECIFICATIONS><WEIGHT>75 lbs.</WEIGHT><POWER>120 Volt</POWER></SPECIFICATIONS>
    <OPTIONS FINISH="Metal" ADAPTER="Optional" CASE="NotApplicable"/>
    <PRICE> <MSRP>1122.99</MSRP><WHOLESALE>654.99</WHOLESALE><SHIPPING>41.00</SHIPPING></PRICE>
    <NOTES>The most powerfull generator made.</NOTES>
</PRODUCT>
<PRODUCT NAME="Hammer" PARTNUM="1" CATEGORY="HandTool">         
    <SPECIFICATIONS><WEIGHT>5 lbs.</WEIGHT></SPECIFICATIONS>
    <PRICE> <MSRP>9.99</MSRP><WHOLESALE>7.99</WHOLESALE><SHIPPING>2.00</SHIPPING></PRICE>
</PRODUCT>
<PRODUCT NAME="Screwdriver" PARTNUM="2" CATEGORY="HandTool">    
    <SPECIFICATIONS><WEIGHT>1 lbs.</WEIGHT></SPECIFICATIONS>
    <PRICE> <MSRP>11.99</MSRP><WHOLESALE>9.99</WHOLESALE><SHIPPING>3.00</SHIPPING></PRICE>
</PRODUCT>
<PRODUCT NAME="Saw" PARTNUM="3" >   
     <SPECIFICATIONS><WEIGHT>3 lbs.</WEIGHT></SPECIFICATIONS>
         <OPTIONS FINISH="Metal" ADAPTER="NotApplicable" CASE="NotApplicable"/>
     <PRICE> <MSRP>5.99</MSRP><WHOLESALE>7.99</WHOLESALE><SHIPPING>2.50</SHIPPING></PRICE>
</PRODUCT>
<PRODUCT NAME="Black and Decker Variable Drill"  PARTNUM="2456" CATEGORY="HandTool">
         <SPECIFICATIONS><WEIGHT>2 lbs." </WEIGHT><POWER>1/3HP</POWER></SPECIFICATIONS>
         <OPTIONS FINISH="Metal" ADAPTER="Included" CASE="HardShell"/>
         <PRICE> <MSRP>35.99</MSRP>
<WHOLESALE>24.95</WHOLESALE><SHIPPING>4.95</SHIPPING></PRICE>
         <NOTES>This item is on clearance.</NOTES>
</PRODUCT>   
<PRODUCT NAME="Black and Decker Rotary Tablesaw" PARTNUM="2364" CATEGORY="Table">
         <SPECIFICATIONS><WEIGHT>25 lbs.</WEIGHT><POWER>2/3HP</POWER></SPECIFICATIONS>
         <OPTIONS FINISH="Metal" ADAPTER="NotApplicable" CASE="NotApplicable"/>
         <PRICE> <MSRP>45.95</MSRP><WHOLESALE>34.95</WHOLESALE><SHIPPING>4.95</SHIPPING></PRICE>
         <NOTES>See Manufacturer's warning label.</NOTES>
</PRODUCT>
<PRODUCT NAME="Black and Decker Workman's Bench" PARTNUM="3446" CATEGORY="Shop-Professional">
         <SPECIFICATIONS><WEIGHT>50 lbs.</WEIGHT></SPECIFICATIONS>
         <OPTIONS FINISH="Matte" ADAPTER="NotApplicable" CASE="NotApplicable"/>
         <PRICE> <MSRP>72.45</MSRP><WHOLESALE>56.99</WHOLESALE><SHIPPING>10.95</SHIPPING></PRICE>
         <NOTES />
</PRODUCT>
</CATALOG>
```

Here is the output I am getting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CATALOG>
   <PRODUCT>
      <PRODUCT/>
      <NAME>18 Volt Cordless DRILL</NAME>
      <PARTNUM>12</PARTNUM>
      <PRODUCT/>
      <NAME>Variable Speed Drill Press</NAME>
      <PARTNUM>76</PARTNUM>
      <PRODUCT/>
      <NAME>Gas powered generator</NAME>
      <PARTNUM>54</PARTNUM>
      <PRODUCT/>
      <NAME>Hammer</NAME>
      <PARTNUM>1</PARTNUM>
      <PRODUCT/>
      <NAME>Screwdriver</NAME>
      <PARTNUM>2</PARTNUM>
      <PRODUCT/>
      <NAME>Saw</NAME>
      <PARTNUM>3</PARTNUM>
      <PRODUCT/>
      <NAME>Black and Decker Variable Drill</NAME>
      <PARTNUM>2456</PARTNUM>
      <PRODUCT/>
      <NAME>Black and Decker Rotary Tablesaw</NAME>
      <PARTNUM>2364</PARTNUM>
      <PRODUCT/>
      <NAME>Black and Decker Workman's Bench</NAME>
      <PARTNUM>3446</PARTNUM>
      <PRODUCT/>
   </PRODUCT>
</CATALOG>
```

Here is the output I am trying to retrieve

```
<CATALOG>
       <PRODUCT>
          <NAME>18 Volt Cordless DRILL</NAME>
          <PARTNUM>12</PARTNUM>
       <PRODUCT/>
       <PRODUCT>   
           <NAME>Variable Speed Drill Press</NAME>
          <PARTNUM>76</PARTNUM>
      <PRODUCT/>
      <PRODUCT>   
          <NAME>Gas powered generator</NAME>
          <PARTNUM>54</PARTNUM>
     <PRODUCT/>
<!---And so on, you get the idea-->        
</CATALOG>
```

Here is the xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="CATALOG">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/CATALOG"/>    
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:element name="PRODUCT" >
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>  
    </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="PRODUCT">
        <xsl:element name="NAME">
            <xsl:value-of select="@NAME"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="PARTNUM">
            <xsl:value-of select="@PARTNUM"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What XSLT have you tried? Can you paste your code in?

Comment: Sorry forgot xslt, ill post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have the identity transform in there, as you only want a very limited and specific subset. But, this should do the trick:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/CATALOG">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates />
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PRODUCT">
     <xsl:copy>
        <NAME><xsl:value-of select="@NAME"/></NAME>
        <PARTNUM><xsl:value-of select="@PARTNUM"/></PARTNUM>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your Input XML gives this:

```
<CATALOG>
    <PRODUCT>
        <NAME>18 Volt Cordless DRILL</NAME>
        <PARTNUM>12</PARTNUM>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <NAME>Variable Speed Drill Press</NAME>
        <PARTNUM>76</PARTNUM>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <NAME>Gas powered generator</NAME>
        <PARTNUM>54</PARTNUM>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <NAME>Hammer</NAME>
        <PARTNUM>1</PARTNUM>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <NAME>Screwdriver</NAME>
        <PARTNUM>2</PARTNUM>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <NAME>Saw</NAME>
        <PARTNUM>3</PARTNUM>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <NAME>Black and Decker Variable Drill</NAME>
        <PARTNUM>2456</PARTNUM>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <NAME>Black and Decker Rotary Tablesaw</NAME>
        <PARTNUM>2364</PARTNUM>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <NAME>Black and Decker Workman's Bench</NAME>
        <PARTNUM>3446</PARTNUM>
    </PRODUCT>
</CATALOG>
```